# How do I join by new line

Tags: ruby

I am reading a file which has source code. I need to append 2 spaces before each line. This is what I am doing.

```
data = read_file
data.split(/\n/).collect {|l| '  ' + l}.join('\n')
```

However after joining when I do puts then it prints \n literally and it is not a line break. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You need to use a **double quote** (`"`) instead of a single quote. So replace this:

```
'\n'
```

with this:

```
"\n"
```

Read more about it [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings).

You might want to use `\r\n` instead if you want your line-endings to be `CRLF` instead of `LF` (some Windows editors such as Notepad won't see a `LF` linebreak).

Comment: Wouldn't `print "\n"` in ruby print `\r\n` on Windows machines, unless you set the output to binary mode?

Answer (score -14):

I was able to finally get this to work for my application by using

```
"<br>"
```

Comment: While this answer it may be appropriate if the problem involved HTML, this question doesn't mention HTML.